# Xcode 6.1 acting weird with git

Tags: xcode, git, xcode6, diff

I use quite often some git features from XCode like: view diff, blame, filter files by git status. Other than that, I pretty much use the console.

But XCode started acting weird. If I try to see a diff it says:

> This file does not exist at the requested revision.

Another example - if I have 3 modified files and try to filter by git status (lower left corner, the repo icon) it does this: sometimes only 2 files show up as modified - after 2 or 3 seconds it shows the third file, but not the first two. And it switches between like every 2 or 3 seconds.

I tried cloning the repo again. Deleting derived data. Add/Remove repo from xcode preferences. Restart.
I don't know what to do anymore. Reinstall?

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Reinstalling Xcode did the trick.</strike>

If this reappears, try deleting:
`~/Library/Developer/Xcode` and restarting Xcode.